# R colSum for two every two rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggeling with the following(easy) problem but cannot find a good solution to it. Consider a df as follows:

```
test<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
test2<-sample(1:6)
test3<-data.frame(test,test2)
```

I would like to have a third column that in the second row shows ratio of row 1:2 of column 2, in the fourth row the ratio 3:4 of column2 and in the sixth row the ratio 5:6 of column2. My df is by far larger otherwise I would have done by hand:)
Any suggestions on how to do that? i know that you can get the diff with the diff command but the ratio? And how do I bind to rows together? split() does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty fast:

```
test3$ratio <- NA
test3$ratio[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- test3$test2[c(FALSE, TRUE)] /
                               test3$test2[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gl` to generate your groups:

```
temp <- within(test3, {
  Sums <- ave(test2, gl(nrow(test3)/2, 2), FUN = function(x) x[2]/x[1])
  Sums[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- NA
})

temp
#   test test2     Sums
# 1    A     2       NA
# 2    B     6 3.000000
# 3    C     3       NA
# 4    D     4 1.333333
# 5    E     1       NA
# 6    F     5 5.000000
```

Alternatively (and similar to flodel's answer), you can use `head` and `tail`:

```
test3$Sums <- NA
test3$Sums[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- (tail(c(0, test3$test2), -1)/
                                head(c(0, test3$test2), -1))[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
test3
#   test test2     Sums
# 1    A     2       NA
# 2    B     6 3.000000
# 3    C     3       NA
# 4    D     4 1.333333
# 5    E     1       NA
# 6    F     5 5.000000
```

---

For the above, the sample data was:

```
set.seed(1)
test<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
test2<-sample(1:6)
test3<-data.frame(test,test2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loop (instead of 6 below you can put the number of last row in your large dataframe):

```
 for( i in seq(2,6,by=2)) {
test3$ratio[i] <- with(test3,test2[i-1]/test2[i])
}
> test3


   test test2     ratio
1    A     3        NA
2    B     5 0.6000000
3    C     4        NA
4    D     6 0.6666667
5    E     1        NA
6    F     2 0.5000000
```